# how to get another output when same text/string is entered in textbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ado.net

When the same "ID" is entered in the textbox, another output should be created.

ex.
when I enter 123, 124, 125 (individually), they output " Success Login!", and when I enter 123 or either of the "IDs" that are already entered, it will give me this output "Success Logout!".

I have tried storing it to a variable -- public static String StoreUserID; but I think this is the wrong approach since I will be using textbox.Clear(); so it outputs "user logged out" when I dont enter anything :(

```
public static String StoreUserID;
///
private void IDTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                if (IDTextBox.Text != "")
                {
                    FlashMessage.Text = IDTextBox.Text  + " Success Login! " + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                    IDTextBox.Clear();
                }
                else if (StoreUserID == IDTextBox.Text)
                {
                    FlashMessage.Text = IDTextBox.Text + " Success Logout! " + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    FlashMessage.Text = "No ID Entered";
                }
}
```

I expected it to output another message when the same "ID" is entered, but it only outputs "Success Logout!" when there is no text in the textbox.

Comment: I can not understand your requirement. Please give a full set of Expected Inputs and Outputs. I can give you some general advise: Avoid working with strings. As your keywords are Integers, you should consider using Integers - TryParse is your friend here. String comparision is problematic, as it tends towards evaluating "not equal" when you least expect it. Secondly, loggin in our out simply based on typing is a bad pattern. Just make a Login and Logout Button - do not do such far reaching work on a simple keypress.

Comment: The expected output for this is:
when I enter an ID e.g. 123 it outputs "success login", when I enter 123 again on the textbox, it should print "success logout"

Comment: That is perhaps the most counterintuitive way to work with a Programm I have seen in a while. There are so many patterns to choose from - why did you create that one instead?

Comment: I am trying to make a DTR application, I'm just a beginner in c#, and I cant find good documentation for ado.net c#

Comment: I looked up the term DTR, but I can not find out wich defition you meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTR

Comment: what I meant by that was, Daily Time Record, which records the "time in" and "time out" of all employees

Comment: Those are also not designed like this. They are either a Card Reader - wich will raise a Event "reader read number", in wich the code can then do work with the number. Or a keypad with a "comit" button (like the Numpad on a Keyboard or OK Button on a GUI), and that "Button Click" will do the work. You do not use "on keypress" processing, because if they only got a 1-line display, the user would be uncertain if he type in the later number properly.

Comment: do you have any good documentation about this? its very confusing :/

Comment: What documentation? It is basic "learning to programm in Windows Forms". Or Java. Even Webpages follow that pattern. You do nothing to minimal work on input. If there is relevant work to do, you do it on a button press. Simple and reliable like a lightswitch. Take this comment formular. All it does on input it is simple count of used characters and a substraction. 99% this is speedy, client side Javascript. All the serious work of sending the text over the internet together with my login token and the checks that I am allowed to post? That happens on clicking the button "add Comment".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing one vital thing: you don't remember who is logged in and who is not because you never set your `StoreUserID` variable. Because your program only seems capable of remembering a single person at a time, which isn't very useful for a DTR program, I've changed it to a Dictionary. Dictionary is like an array but indexed by a string not an integer and it provides us a way to store when they logged in:

```
    private Dictionary<string, DateTime> _loggedInUsers = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>(); //need to add this at top of file:  using System.Collections.Generic;

    private void IDTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
         {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(IDTextBox.Text)) //usually better than comparing with ""
                {
                    FlashMessage.Text = "No ID Entered";
                    return;
                }

                var user = IDTextBox.Text.Trim(); //remove header/trailing spaces
                IDTextBox.Clear();                //might as well do this now

                if(_loggedInUsers.ContainsKey(user))
                {
                    //how long were they logged in?
                    TimeSpan ts = (DateTime.Now - _loggedInUsers[user]);
                    _loggedInUsers.Remove(user); //log them out
                    FlashMessage.Text = $"{user} successfully logged out at {DateTime.Now}, you were logged in for {ts.TotalHours} hours, which is also {ts.TotalSeconds}. You earned {ts.TotalHours * 200} at your rate of 200$/hr";
                }
                else 
                {   
                    _loggedInUsers[user] = DateTime.Now; //log them in at this time
                    FlashMessage.Text = $"{user} successfully logged in. Go do some work and then log out and I'll tell you how long you were";
                }
          }
    }
```

I also added some other fluff showing you how to use string interpolation but the most critical part is; we put the user into the dictionary when we log them in and take them out when they log out. The string is entered into the dictionary along with the time of login. The string is later used to look up the time of login and gives us a way to calc the hours worked. Removing the user from the dictionary logs them out; it is the "presence" or "not presence" of a user id in the dictionary that determines if they are logged in (presence) or out (not presence)

I put a Trim() command in there because spaces make different strings. If user types `123` upon login, and `123` on "logout" he will log in again because the spaces make these users different things. Users love to do daft things like this and we must protect against them where possible

Comment: I am trying to login and logout users form a .mdf database, is this (your answer) still applicable? sorry for the late reply I have no access to the internet for the past days

Comment: Sure it is still applicable, it's just that a dictionary is the data storage here but you're using a database table instead. If you arrange a few methods that search, read and write the DB then it will slot in

Comment: do you have any good recommendations (tutorials) about dictionary with a .mdf database? I was searching but the data they used in the dictionary was not in the database

Comment: I think I might have been hard to understand. In my example I use a dictionary to store the name and the time, but you can use a database. The database will need to store a name and a time and be able to retrieve a time for any given name. Task yourself to make a helper class that makes a database work like the dictionary here (have lookup and save)

Comment: I'll try to search on how to implement this :D

Comment: Start out by searching for "c# dapper tutorial". Dapper is a technology that can automatically convert your c# objects into database rows and back. It's less heavy weight than something like entity framework and you have to manually write the SQL to get the database to work, which is good for learning database language

Comment: Thank you so much for this dude, I modified the code and got the perfect output.